# How to configure log4j using log4j.xml to append logs to different files based on Logger level and appender?

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

Below is the configuration of my application:

1. Spring and hibernate based web application.
2. The same application is having quartz schedular for some background processing.

Problem:

1. I want web application logs to be stored in different files based on Log level.
2. Logs of schedular should be stored on altogether different set of files based on log level.

I am looking for a way to implement this, but no luck till now.

As per my understanding the problem is due to web application and schedular are both packed in same war file, but that's customer's requirement.

I tried using 2 different loggers, one for web app and another for schedular. But all logs are appended to all the log files irrespective of what logger is used.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Post your `log4j.xml`.